# How do I tell if my Instrument is valid?

Tags: econometrics, causality, instrumental-variables, 2sls

I have the following structural model (similar) which I wish to estimate 
$$
Y_t = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_t + \epsilon_t
$$
but I'm aware that $X_t$ is endogenous or equivalently, $E[X_t\epsilon_t]\ne 0$. Turns out that I have what logically appears to be a valid instrument $Z_t$ that explains $X_t$ and rightfully, $Y_t$ correlates to $Z_t$ only through $X_t$. Using the 2 stage least squares (2SLS) estimation technique, this allows me to define my first stage model as
$$
X_t = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1 Z_t + \eta_t
$$
and recover $\beta_1$ through the following second stage model
$$
Y_t = \theta_0 + \theta_1 \hat{X}_t + \nu_t,
$$
where if I understand correctly, $\theta_1 = \beta_1$ assymptotically.

**My problem** is that even though $Z_t$ seems to be a very reasonable IV, calculating the correlation of the residuals and instrument gives $Cor(\hat{\nu_t},Z_t) \ne 0$. As expected, regressing the residuals of the second stage model with $Z_t$,
$$
\hat{\nu}_t = \gamma_0 + \gamma_1 Z_t + \eta_t,
$$
also results in small but statistically significant estimates of $\gamma_1$.

Does this mean that the exclusion restriction assumption of $Z_t$ is invalid? Because this seems to imply $E[Z_t\epsilon_t]\ne0$ ? Or is $E[Z_t\epsilon_t]$ and $E[Z_t\hat{\nu}]$ two completely different things? If that is the case, is there a remedy? Or at least some general guidelines that allows $Cor(\hat{\nu_t},Z_t) \ne 0$ at the expense of some acceptable bias in the estimates?

---

---

Update:

I did some simple analysis and it appears that correlation between $\hat{\nu}$ and $Z_t$ is to be expected by definition of the 2SLS because
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{Cov(\hat{\nu}_t, Z_t)}{Var(Z_t)} 
&= \frac{Cov(Y_t - \theta_0 - \theta_1 \hat{X}_t, Z_t)}{Var(Z_t)} \\
&= \frac{Cov(Y_t, Z_t)}{Var(Z_t)} - \theta_1\frac{Cov(\hat{X}_t, Z_t)}{Var(Z_t)}\\
&= \frac{Cov(Y_t, Z_t)}{Var(Z_t)} - \theta_1\frac{Cov(\alpha_0 + \alpha_1Z_t + \eta_t, Z_t)}{Var(Z_t)}\\
&= \frac{Cov(Y_t, Z_t)}{Var(Z_t)} - \theta_1\alpha_1\frac{Cov(Z_t, Z_t)}{Var(Z_t)}\\
&= \frac{Cov(Y_t, Z_t)}{Var(Z_t)} - \theta_1\alpha_1.
\end{aligned}
$$
Implying $\gamma_1 = \theta_1\alpha_1$. Indeed, my estimate is $\hat{\gamma}_1 \approx \hat{\alpha}_1\hat{\theta}_1$. Hence, this implies that $E[Z_t\epsilon_t]$ is not the same thing as $E[Z_t\hat{\nu}_t]$. Does this make sense or did I make a mistake somewhere?

Comment: You cannot test instrument validity without over-identifying restrictions. In the simplest reduced form IV scenario that you have, it means you need to have more excluded instruments than the number of endogenous variables.

Comment: @tchakravarty   Yes, you are right. That verification comes through the Sargan-Hansen test. Unfortunately it doesn't tell us which of the instruments (possibly all) are endogenous. Was trying to understand why my residuals are correlated to my instruments and I think the above explains why.